# AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0 - Error Often

Tags: android-studio-3.2

I need you help and your support
Now, I'm on procces to build my project mobile apps with android studio
Why the R Layout always error once open the project and if try new project and R Layout can not be generated R layout.

Could help me please to solve this problem

```
    Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\sreza\AndroidStudioProjects\AttGeo\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: D:\sreza\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\daa36f831bb51fbb5d94ececae2a282c\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\sreza\AndroidStudioProjects\AttGeo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\sreza\AndroidStudioProjects\AttGeo\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, could you rephrase your question? It's very difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Can you also share the code of the file `D:\sreza\AndroidStudioProjects\AttGeo\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml`?